# How to solve error installing setuptools python in windows

Tags: python, windows, flask, virtualenv, setuptools

can someone help me with an issue I am struggling for a couple of hours, I am trying to install "flask-jwt-extended" using

```
pip install flask-jwt-extended
```

but I am getting the following error

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-fg_ccsgv\\flask-jwt-extended\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-fg_ccsgv\\flask-jwt-extended\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fg_ccsgv\flask-jwt-extended\
    Complete output (3 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

It says I have to install setuptools, but I already have installed it.

`Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\lib\site-packages (41.2.0)`

Can someone help me out with that? I don't know what can it be

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried using `python -m pip install <package>` instead of `pip install <package>`?

Comment: @kuco23 Yes I have!

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install gitpython

pip install os-win

pip install wheel
```

Use `sudo` for Linux or `run cmd as Administrator` for Windows.

This solved the issue for me.

Comment: Please format your code in the answers.
See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)