# Why does `pip install -e` give me a "no module named 'setuptools'" error even though I have setuptools installed?

Tags: python, pip, conda

I am trying to install a work-in-progress package in a conda environment as an editable package via `pip install -e`, but I get a "no module named 'setuptools'", even though I have verified that setuptools is properly installed in the environment (I can import it in a python session inside the environment).

I have a minimal `setup.py`:

```
import setuptools

if __name__ == "__main__":
    setuptools.setup()
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this and install my package in an editable state? I also looked at [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62983756/what-is-pyproject-toml-file-for) but did not find a suitable answer for my case.

Full error traceback below:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /nfs/nhome/live/jbhagat/.conda/envs/aeon_env/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/ceph/aeon/aeon/code/ProjectAeon/aeon/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/ceph/aeon/aeon/code/ProjectAeon/aeon/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' develop --no-deps
         cwd: /ceph/aeon/aeon/code/ProjectAeon/aeon/
    Complete output (3 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'
```

**Edit**: **Update**: Interestingly, if I comment out all lines in my `setup.py` file I get the same error. If I delete my `setup.py`, I get an error stating that a `setup.py` is necessary to install an editable package.

Comment: what message do you get when you run pip install setuptools

Comment: "Requirement already satisfied" and it points to where it should in my conda env

Comment: Related, might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14426491.

Comment: `pip install -U pip` solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not sure exactly what's going on, but it appears to be pip related. These are two related situations I found:

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58001889/how-to-solve-error-installing-setuptools-python-in-windows)

[2](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/4474#issuecomment-71721163)

My solution was just to use `python setup.py develop` instead of `pip install -e` : this sets up an .egg-link in my site-packages dir which points to my project code dir to allow for imports, which was good enough for me.